# Perl convert short to one byte

Tags: perl, byte, short

Does anyone know how I would go about convert two bytes from a file to just one byte?
I have tried to read in two bytes into every element of an array and then divide it by 6553 and times by 255 to convert to one byte. However that does not work. 
Any suggestions please?

```
open my $fh, '<:raw', $test;
my @info = do {
    local $/ = \2;
    <$fh>;
};
close($fh);

foreach(@info){
    $_= (($_)/65535)*255;
}
my $temp = "temp.txt";

open(TEMP, ">", $temp);
print TEMP my $info;
close(TEMP);
```

ERRORS:

```
Argument "\0^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^A^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^B^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^E^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^G^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^H^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
Argument "^G^B" isn't numeric in division (/) at ./con.pl line 33.
```

Comment: Convert 16 to 8bit in which way?

Comment: @mpapec
I don't understand what you mean by 'which way'?

Comment: How should ie. `65535,65280,..` be converted to one byte? What are converted values for mentioned numbers?

Comment: @mpapec well I thought I would be able to take two bytes, divide by 65535 and then multiply by 255

Comment: You should at least know what are desired results for particular values before asking a question.

Comment: I do know the desired results. If my values in the file are from 0 - 65535
the new values should become 0-255
65535 becomes 255
0 stays 0
the middle value would be 127

Comment: Your method works, you just need to round decimal numbers.

Comment: I just get argument isn't numeric divison errors

Comment: To be able to divide and multiply, you have to convert a char to a number. Use [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) for that.

Comment: What about `'<:encoding(UTF-16LE)'` or so instead of raw? Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If bytes are coming from the file, convert them to numbers. That's what [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) is for:

```
$c = "\x1\x2";
print unpack 'n', $c;
```

Output: `258`.

Use [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) to convert the number back to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
pack 'C', unpack 'n', $twobytes;            # Big-endian input
pack 'C', unpack 'v', $twobytes;            # Little-endian input
pack 'C*', unpack 'n*', $many_byte_pairs;   # Big-endian input
pack 'C*', unpack 'v*', $many_byte_pairs;   # Little-endian input
```

Checking for overflow is left to you.